# ADB shell not detecting device if not logged on host (SSH'ing into host before logging in)

Tags: android, linux, adb

Not sure if I'm using the right terminology but I'll be happy to fix it!

Anyways, I'm attempting to use a linux box as my testing host which has all my android devices connected to it and devices can be seen using, 'adb devices'. However, if there is a power failure or auto update which resets the host, the computer boots up but is not logged in. At this state, I am able to ssh into the host but when I execute, 'adb devices', I cannot see any devices. Only after I login can I see the devices again.

Would anyone know a workaround to this by any chance?

I have rules setup as room under /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

The questionable item is that I have /Users/kev/.android/adb_usb.ini which may be causing the problem. but if I ssh in using that account, wouldn't it be the same as logging in the gnome login?

thanks!